# Can the translation for "you're welcome" be "mū"?

Tags: translation, words

A Japanese-addict friend of mine recently told me that a possible translation for "you're welcome" in Japanese was "mū", but I must admit I was a bit dubious about that since I had never seen it nor heard it. I looked it up and found no entries about it anywhere.

Is it a mistake?

Comment: "Japanese addict"... So a weeaboo, correct? It's likely she's misinformed as I've never heard this in all my time of studying.

Comment: I have never heard  "mū" as the meaning of "you're welcome". I think "you're welcome" is almost translated as どういたしまして.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely a mistake. The only time I hear of むー is in comics where it's the sound effect for thinking (I think you use hmmm in English). So, my theory is this person heard a conversation like...

Akimori: I did your laundry for you.

Yamada: Hmmm...but I thought I asked Ken to do it.

And might have thought むー was "you're welcome" when it was just the person thinking about something, haha.

Comment: This むー is pronounced as a long 'm' sound, not as it's spelt. Of course, your answer still holds if they read such a conversation.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. I mean, if it was a direct むう in speech or whatever then I would have no idea, haha.

Comment: The sounds effect for thinking in Japanese are うーん,んー、んーと. I have never heard むー.

Comment: It would seem you're right. http://thejadednetwork.com/sfx/search/?keyword=muu&submitSearch=Search+SFX&x=

My bad... Hehe

Answer (score 3):

It is possible if the individual/character answering is: male(most likely), stoic, non-talkative, old-fashion (think samurai-stereotype of old) answering a 'thank you' from someone.  (Most novels I read with characters answering like
this would fit this description).

Might be more of a うむ～ but it could be むー depending on the writer or character.

Comment: Great answer!  Could not think of that one myself!

Comment: I think samurai like you said say うむ but they don't say むー.